# Different output from apply() and adply()

Tags: r, plyr

I can't figure out why `adply()` returns me a `data.frame` that includes the original variables, while `apply()` doesn't. Basically, it looks like `adply()` is just another `mutate()`. What am I missing?

Test data:

```
library(pacman)
p_load(plyr)

g_loadings = c(.50, .60, .80,
               .60, .70, .60,
               .80, .50, .30)

group_1_loadings = c(.50, .50, .50,
                     0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0)

group_2_loadings = c(0, 0, 0,
                     .50, .50, .50,
                     0, 0, 0)

group_3_loadings = c(0, 0, 0,
                     0, 0, 0,
                     .50, .50, .50)

d = data.frame(g_loadings,
               group_1_loadings,
               group_2_loadings,
               group_3_loadings)
```

`adply()`:

```
adply(d, 1, function(x) {
  var_g_group = sum(x^2)
  var_remain = 1 - var_g_group
  loading_specificity = sqrt(var_remain)
  return(loading_specificity)
  }
)
```

Returns:

```
  g_loadings group_1_loadings group_2_loadings group_3_loadings        V1
1        0.5              0.5              0.0              0.0 0.7071068
2        0.6              0.5              0.0              0.0 0.6244998
3        0.8              0.5              0.0              0.0 0.3316625
4        0.6              0.0              0.5              0.0 0.6244998
5        0.7              0.0              0.5              0.0 0.5099020
6        0.6              0.0              0.5              0.0 0.6244998
7        0.8              0.0              0.0              0.5 0.3316625
8        0.5              0.0              0.0              0.5 0.7071068
9        0.3              0.0              0.0              0.5 0.8124038
```

`apply()`:

```
apply(d, 1, function(x) {
  var_g_group = sum(x^2)
  var_remain = 1 - var_g_group
  loading_specificity = sqrt(var_remain)
  return(loading_specificity)
  }
)
```

Returns:

```
[1] 0.7071068 0.6244998 0.3316625 0.6244998 0.5099020 0.6244998 0.3316625 0.7071068 0.8124038
```

Why doesn't `adply()` return the same as `apply()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naming convention of those `plyr` functions is the first letter corresponds the data structure it operates on, the second to the data structure it returns.  So, `adply` operates on array and returns `data.frame`.  You can use the `.expand` option to specify columns to return.

```
adply(d, 1, function(x) {
  var_g_group = sum(x^2)
  var_remain = 1 - var_g_group
  loading_specificity = sqrt(var_remain)
  return(loading_specificity)
  }, .expand=F)
#   X1        V1
# 1  1 0.7071068
# 2  2 0.6244998
# 3  3 0.3316625
# 4  4 0.6244998
# 5  5 0.5099020
# 6  6 0.6244998
# 7  7 0.3316625
# 8  8 0.7071068
# 9  9 0.8124038
```

Or get back an array with `aaply` (this would be the same as what is returned by `apply`, except `apply` uses `as.vector` on the result)

```
aaply(d, 1, function(x) {
  var_g_group = sum(x^2)
  var_remain = 1 - var_g_group
  loading_specificity = sqrt(var_remain)
  return(loading_specificity)
  }, .expand=F)
#         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
# 0.7071068 0.6244998 0.3316625 0.6244998 0.5099020 0.6244998 0.3316625 0.7071068 
#         9 
# 0.8124038
```

Comment: I know the naming conventions. However, I would expect `adply()` to return an data.frame with one column, not the original dataset plus the new column. I don't understand why. Even specifying `.expand = F` as you did, makes it return a data.frame with two columns, not one. So to use `adply()` one has to add a `[2]` to get the right column.

As you say, `aaply()`, which I of course also tried, does not give the right result either. It gives a nonsensical result, which apparently must be fixed with the `.expand = F` parameter.

Comment: @Deleet if you don't want the id column then just pass `.id=NULL` as an additional parameter to `adply`.  I agree about `aaply()`, I think apply is usually preferred